# convert blob to string and display string value in visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, notes

1. convert blob value to string. I have used

   ```
   body1 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(termsandconditionsAttach.body);
   body1=termsandconditionsAttach.Body.toString();
   ```

these methods to convert. but the problem is original data is not diplaying in vf page

2. Please share your knowledge

Comment: How do you know for certain the original blob was a string as opposed to html or other content such as rich text? How are you trying to display it in your visualforce?

Comment: using apex:output text using this i want to display

Comment: that isn't going to work but you could use a dataURI to display the content in say an IFrame

Comment: ok send in that way

Comment: What format is your body?

Comment: I want to string from blob

Comment: I have a similar issue but want to display the Blob image in a 3rd party system. I get the an image from a salesforce attachment in the form of string through a service returning me JSON data. When i try to read this image string, it does not get correctly displayed on the page. I am reading the string as a bytearrayinputstream and converting to byte[] to store it. Any pointers?

Comment: This can be help: https://sfdcian.com/convert-string-into-blob-and-blob-into-string-using-apex-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an Attachment in Visualforce, you don't want to convert it to a string and then send to the frontend. Rather, you want to have the Attachment Id and then display a link to download the attachment like so

```
<a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!AttachmentId}">Download</a>
```

In that case, also don't load the Attachment Body in the SOQL query, because that is unnecessary. You only need the Id.

Comment: if we using this we may get download link. My intention is to display attachment body data in vf page as string format

Comment: Okay, then it depends on how you stored the String into the Attachment.Body Blob in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find some information abount the attachments, https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yZ8IAI

some other information on encoding (that may help ) can be read here [Attachment UTF-8 Character Set](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16157/attachment-utf-8-character-set)

To show the body of an attachment, you can use what is suggested by the fist link:

```
String bodyContent = myAttachment.body.toString();
```

and than you can use a method, or can define a public variable accessible from the page:

```
public string bodyContent{get;set;}
```

... some where in the controller set it...

or you can create a method getter that may be refered by the page

```
public string getBodyContent(){
    return myAttachment.body.toString();
}
```

if is not clear, please say me i will be more specific. For a more specific answere, please leave also the use case and specifics.

K.

Comment: i did this one also but when i run  vf page i get one error blob value must be utf like this type of error

Answer (score 0):

If your attachment is text file, try blob .toString()

Comment: I used this one also, when i run vf page then showing a error Blob Base 64, Utf like some error